# What is the reason my app crashes below android 6.0?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and I made an app which is working on all android but not working below android 6.0 and the error states that "Inflates Welcome Activity"
So, I am providing my welcome activity screen code as well as my gradle codes.
Please do check and if anyone can find out the error it would be great.
Thanks in advance

Welcome activity code:

```
package com.divesh.sliderapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private TextView[] dots;
private int[] layouts;
private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
private PrefManager prefManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


    // layouts of all welcome sliders
    // add few more layouts if you want
    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.welcome_slide1,
            R.layout.welcome_slide2,
            R.layout.welcome_slide3,
            R.layout.welcome_slide4};

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}

//  viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);

        // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            // last page. make button text to GOT IT
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // still pages are left
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

/**
 * Making notification bar transparent
 */
private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

}

Gradle Files:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()



    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The other Gradle File:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()



    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.divesh.sliderapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>

    <application
        android:name=".sliderapp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".payment" />
        <activity android:name=".Information" />
        <activity android:name=".PaymentSuccess" />
        <activity android:name=".PaymentError"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: change the other gradle image

Comment: It would be great if you could post your stack trace here so people can help you

Comment: share your logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       in your code -  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            }

    &&

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 

    you defined here API LEVEL >= 21 so is crashing below API level.

ADD this code to stop  crashing.

private void setUpActionBar() {
    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i call setUpActionbar()

Comment: in onCreate method Of Activtiy .